# SQL Server 2012 - Msg 8114 - bug?

Tags: sql-server, data-import

[1.1 Source (temp) file (columns/properties)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FYYcU.png)

[2.1 interim TEMP table - same table/column structure as destination table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oPOX9.png)

I've tried everything to insert data from a temp table into a main table, and it continues to throw an error

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 1

I've double-checked that the number of required columns is compatible (plus column names), have ensured that the data-type is exactly the same (including decimals), and have populated the 'null' columns with a dummy numeric (9999.99). So every column that looks like a number IS a number, every column that ISN'T a number has a leading alpha. There are no cases or casts or converts, it's just a direct transfer.

[screenshot source table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M4KP3.png)

To all intents they're EXACTLY the same.  What am I missing?

I'm saving the source data as a .csv, using task>import, changing column data type and adding dummy numerics, then TRYING to import into main table.  I've tried on 5 different source tables.  Help!

Is there a bug I can't find? Is there a patch?

CODE (attempt to cast 1 row of defaults as destination data) :

```sql
/****** Script for SelectTopNRows command from SSMS  ******/
SELECT TOP 1
cast('blah' as varchar(5)) as [PROJECT]--
,cast('blah' as varchar(5)) as [SITE_ID]--
,cast('blah' as varchar(5)) AS[SAMPLE_ID]--
,cast(8.99 as decimal(8,2)) AS [DEPTH_FROM]--
,cast(9.99 as decimal(8,2)) AS [DEPTH_TO]--
,cast('blah' as varchar(5)) as [SAMPLE_CATEGORY]--
,cast('blah' as varchar(5)) AS [SAMPLE_TYPE]--
,cast('blah' as varchar(5)) as [SAMPLE_METHOD]--
,cast('b' as varchar(1)) as [SAMPLE_CONDITION]--
,cast('blah' as varchar(5)) as [SAMPLE_RECOVERY]
,cast(getdate() as date) as [DATE_SAMPLED]
,cast('blah' as varchar(5)) as [SAMPLED_BY]
,cast('blah' as varchar(5)) as [COMMENTS]
,cast('blah' as varchar(5)) as [DATA_SOURCE]
,cast(0.999 as decimal(12,4)) as [Ag_ppm]
,cast(0.999 as decimal(12,4))  as [Al_pct]
,cast(0.999 as decimal(12,4)) as [Al_ppm]
,cast(0.999 as decimal(12,4))   as [As_pct]
,cast(0.999 as decimal(12,4))  as [As_ppm]
,cast(0.999 as decimal(12,4))  as [Au_ppb]
,cast(0.999 as decimal(12,4))  as [Au_ppm]
,cast(0.999 as decimal(12,4))  as [Ba_ppm]
,cast(0.999 as decimal(12,4))  as [Bi_ppm]
,cast(0.999 as decimal(12,4))  as [Ca_ppm]
,cast(0.999 as decimal(12,4))  as [Cd_ppm]
,cast(0.999 as decimal(12,4))  as [Ce_ppm]
,cast(0.999 as decimal(12,4))   as Co_pct
,cast(0.999 as decimal(12,4))  as [Co_ppm]
,cast(0.999 as decimal(12,4))   as [Cr_pct]
,cast(0.999 as decimal(12,4))  as [Cr_ppm]
,cast(0.999 as decimal(12,4))   as [Cu_pct]
,cast(0.999 as decimal(12,4))  as [Cu_ppm]
,cast(0.999 as decimal(12,4))  as [Dy_ppm]
,cast(0.999 as decimal(12,4))  as [Er_ppm]
,cast(0.999 as decimal(12,4))  as [Eu_ppm]
,cast(0.999 as decimal(12,4))   as [Fe_pct]
,cast(0.999 as decimal(12,4))  as [Fe_ppm]
,cast(0.999 as decimal(12,4))  as [Gd_ppm]
,cast(0.999 as decimal(12,4))  as [Ho_ppm]
,cast(0.999 as decimal(12,4))  as [K_ppm]
,cast(0.999 as decimal(12,4))  as [La_ppm]
,cast(0.999 as decimal(12,4))  as [Lu_ppm]
,cast(0.999 as decimal(12,4))  as [Mg_pct]
,cast(0.999 as decimal(12,4))  as [Mg_ppm]
,cast(0.999 as decimal(12,4))  as [Mn_pct]
,cast(0.999 as decimal(12,4))  as [Mn_ppm]
,cast(0.999 as decimal(12,4))  as [Na_pct]
,cast(0.999 as decimal(12,4))  as [Na_ppm]
,cast(0.999 as decimal(12,4))  as [Nd_ppm]
,cast(0.999 as decimal(12,4))   as [Ni_pct]
,cast(0.999 as decimal(12,4))  as [Ni_ppm]
,cast(0.999 as decimal(12,4))   as [P_pct]
,cast(0.999 as decimal(12,4))   as [Pb_pct]
,cast(0.999 as decimal(12,4))  as [Pb_ppm]
,cast(0.999 as decimal(12,4))  as [Pd_ppb]
,cast(0.999 as decimal(12,4))  as [Pr_ppm]
,cast(0.999 as decimal(12,4))  as [Pt_ppb]
,cast(0.999 as decimal(12,4))  as [S_pct]
,cast(0.999 as decimal(12,4))  as [Sb_ppm]
,cast(0.999 as decimal(12,4))  as [Se_ppm]
,cast(0.999 as decimal(12,4))  as [Si_ppm]
,cast(0.999 as decimal(12,4))  as [Sm_ppm]
,cast(0.999 as decimal(12,4))  as [Sn_ppm]
,cast(0.999 as decimal(12,4))  as [Tb_ppm]
,cast(0.999 as decimal(12,4))  as [Te_ppm]
,cast(0.999 as decimal(12,4))  as [Ti_ppm]
,cast(0.999 as decimal(12,4))  as [Tm_ppm]
,cast(0.999 as decimal(12,4))  as [U_ppm]
,cast(0.999 as decimal(12,4))  as [V_ppm]
,cast(0.999 as decimal(12,4))  as [W_ppm]
,cast(0.999 as decimal(12,4))  as [Y_ppm]
,cast(0.999 as decimal(12,4))  as [Yb_ppm]
,cast(0.999 as decimal(12,4))  as [Zn_pct]
,cast(0.999 as decimal(12,4))  as [Zn_ppm]
,cast(0.999 as decimal(12,4))  as [Zr_ppm]
,cast('blah' as varchar(5)) as [REPORT]
,cast(0.999 as decimal(12,4))  as [Mo_ppm]

FROM      
    [TIGERWULF].[dbo].[ASSAY_a91728]
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates an error converting a varchar to a float. Try importing everything as varchar into a temporary table then CAST the number columns from varchar to decimal as you insert them into your final table.

Comment: yup, tried that.  The destination table doesn't have any floats.

Comment: The destination table appears to have `decimal` columns, which are the same as floats.

Comment: ah.  Thanks daShier